# How to remove submitted URL from Google Search Console?

Tags: google-search-console, sitemap

I am working on an e-commerce website (similar to ebay) with a lot of categories.

Being a new e-commerce a lot of categories are empty (have no products).

Initially, I made a sitemap containing a link to each and every single category, and submitted the sitemap to Google... then I got the following error for the empty categories:

> Submitted URL returns soft 404

So then I changed the sitemap. The new sitemap includes a link to only those categories which have at least one product. The menu still contains a link to empty categories but I have marked the link as `nofollow` and the empty category page has `noindex` meta tag. So I am trying to tell the crawlers to not index the empty category pages...

The sitemap is updated every 2 hours, so if the category changes and gets populated with products, I would include it in the sitemap and remove the `nofollow` and `noindex` meta tags.

Now Google Search Console is showing me the following error:

> Submitted URL marked ‘noindex’

[image]

I believe this is because Google had previously indexed the empty category pages... but now the same page is marked as `noindex`, however this page no longer exists in the new sitemap.

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Why do you need to remove this message? It looks like it is telling you things are working the way you want.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller: thanks for your comment. I have included a screenshot in the question, the pages are marked with `error`... that's why I want to fix them.

Comment: I'd just leave it.  Having errors there doesn't hurt your site at all.  You've already taken the appropriate action.

Comment: Most errors I encounter end up fixed if I do nothing.